# Discord Bot to DM specific roles

Tags: python, bots, discord

been trying to get a workaround on this code from another guy but i can't get it to work... here is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import bot
from discord import game
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import platform
import colorsys
import random
import time

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', case_insensitive=True)
Client = discord.client
Clientdiscord = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as '+client.user.name+' (ID:'+client.user.id+') | Connected to '+str(len(client.servers))+' servers | Connected to '+str(len(set(client.get_all_members())))+' users')
    print('--------')
    print('--------')

@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)     
async def userinfo(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    r, g, b = tuple(int(x * 255) for x in colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(random.random(), 1, 1))
    embed = discord.Embed(title="{}'s info".format(user.name), description="Here's what I could find.", color = discord.Color((r << 16) + (g << 8) + b))
    embed.add_field(name="Name", value=user.name, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="ID", value=user.id, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Status", value=user.status, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Highest role", value=user.top_role)
    embed.add_field(name="Joined", value=user.joined_at)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
    await client.say(embed=embed)

@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def send(ctx, *, content: str):
        for member in ctx.message.server.members:
            try:
                await client.send_message(member, content)
                await client.say("DM Sent To : {} :white_check_mark:  ".format(member))
            except:
                print("can't")
                await client.say("DM can't Sent To : {} :x: ".format(member))


client.run("TOKEN")
```

The code works to send a DM to EVERYONE in a Discord Server but, what I want is to send DMs to specific roles, i.e: !send role message.

Thanks in advance for the help

PS: It's not a bot for public publishing, I'm just trying to make an efficient announcement system for my guild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using a tutorial for the old version of discord.py, or some sort of mesh between the two versions.

There have been some [major changes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) between then and now in the most recent - rewrite - version.

## Your command rewritten:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", case_insensitive=True)
# you don't need discord.Client()

# this is dming users with a certain role
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.command()
async def announce(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, msg): # announces to the specified role
    global members
    members = [m for m in ctx.guild.members if role in m.roles]
    for m in members:
        try:
            await m.send(msg)
            await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: Message sent to {m}")
        except:
            await ctx.send(f":x: No DM could be sent to {m}")
    await ctx.send("Done!")
@announce.error
# feel free to add another decorator here if you wish for it to send the same messages
# for the same exceptions: e.g. @userinfo.error
async def _announcement_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send(":x: Role couldn't be found!")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f":x: {ctx.author.mention}, you don't have sufficient permissions.")
    else:
        await ctx.send(error)
```

---

**References:**

- [`commands.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context)
- [`commands.has_permissions()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions)
- [`Context.invoke()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.invoke)
- [`Member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.roles)
- [`Guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members)
- [`Command.error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.error) - catch errors for specific commands
- [Exceptions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#exceptions)
- [F-Strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) - Python 3.6+

Comment: Use your solution and made it work but now i have another problem. When tries to send a DM and the user has the bot blocked, instead of getting ":x: Message couldn't be sent to {m}" I'm getting "Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code 50007): Cannot send messages to this user.

I want it to tell whos is the user, clearly the "await ctx.send(f":x: Message couldn't be sent to {m}")" isn't working as intended =(

Alittle bit of help would be apporeciated, thanks in advance =)

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot I could handle that exception in the error handler haha. Edited the code for that case ^

Comment: Well, tryied that edit and now I'm getting "NameError: name 'members' is not defined"  in this line "await ctx.send(f":x: Couldn't DM the following users: {', '.join([str(m) for m in members])}")" and then it says "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'members' is not defined" what is pretty much the same... I'm banging my head against the wall right now xD

Comment: Really sorry about that, messed around with it myself and got it working. Might be a bit messy, but it gets the job done!

Comment: Man, don't worry and thanks for taking the time ;)
Now it send the DM perfectly but when it can't there is no message sent on the chat, just the Done! (https://imgur.com/iqV4eOn) and I don't want it to blacklist ppl, just want to know who has blocked the announce bot and kick her/his door down violently (? Btw, i blacklisted myself on the bot and now i can't test it cuz if i unblock it, it just ignores me and doesn't send the DM... sry to be a pain in the ass dude and thanks again for your time and effort.

Comment: I might've thrown around the word blacklist incorrectly. What's happening is that if the code errors, it adds the member to a list to ignore so that it doesn't error again. Then it runs the command again `await ctx.invoke(....` and it keeps doing so until all the members have been DMed. I'm using the list `errors` and `sent` just to keep track of which members the bot has tried to send a DM to. What you can do is after `Done!` is sent, you can empty the `errors` and `sent` list. That way the bot won't carry on ignoring you.

Comment: Hmmm ok, but that doesn't fix the problem where there is no message sent on bot channel  when it can't reach someone. I blocked the bot, then i sent a DM to a role only i have and the bot just said "Done!" instead of Couldn't DM blah blah" btw, stackoverflow is encouraging us to go on chat instead of writting a thousand comments, wanna go?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214110/discussion-between-ew0h-and-diggy).